# How to run 'scrapy crawl spider.py' as subprocess in windows machine without install python and scrapy?

Tags: python, py2exe

I am calling a subprocess from gui python application in windows machine

```
sub.Popen(['scrapy','crawl','product','-a,'start_url='+self.url],shell=True)
```

And that windows machine won't have python and scrapy.When am running it neither give any error nor run properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running with shell=True you will need to have the scrapy binary on the machine it is running on.

Running python without process would have to be done by compiling the python as an exe and running those binaries on the target machine. See [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) for details on compiling your python code.

Comment: python script is running fine, but what about 'Scrapy'. i don't know how to include scrapy lib.when I call 'scrapy crwal spider.py ' in won't work..

Comment: What is the command line that you can use to get scrapy to work?
Python's subprocess with shell = true should take a string identical to this. eg subprocess.call('tail -f tmp.txt', shell=True)
calling a subprocess with a list of arguments as you have here should have shell=False.
Additionally, where is your scrapy binary? You need to call that. If scrapy has relative directory dependencies you should look into the 'cwd' argument to Popen/subprocess.call.